# Java Generics Type Inference Confusion

Tags: java, type-inference, generic-programming

All,
To test the Java Generics Type Inference I created below sample code.

```
public static <U> U addBox2(U u1, U u2) {
    return u2;
}

static interface A {}
static interface B {}
static class S {}
static class C extends S implements A,B {}
static class D extends S implements B,A {}
```

If you see above A and S have no relationship.

In the code below -

```
A a = addBox2(new C(),new D());
```

I was hoping to receive the compilation error since the type inferred was S and I am assigning it to A and A and S has no relationship still this worked just fine.

Can someone help me explain why this behavior?

Comment: A and S don't have a relationship but since you pass a C and D to the method and both implement A (and B) they have something in common, i.e. they both are As. Besides that everything you pass will be an `Object` and that will be the least common denominator.

Comment: Why do you think it would be type `S`? Why do you ignore the implemented interfaces `A` and `B`?

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA for development and IDEA shows me that T is inferred as S. May be IntelliJ is showing me the wrong thing.

Comment: I have tried the same example in eclipse and when I hover on `addBox` in eclipse I see below **<? extends S> ? extends S Example2.addBox2(? extends S u1, ? extends S u2)** which means U is anything that extends S but A does not extends from S then why there is no compilation error.

Comment: I believe Thomas' comment should be the answer to the question, but it is a comment. @Thomas, why don't you put it as an answer?

Comment: @skw I still can post it ;)

Answer (score 2):

As requested:

`A` and `S` don't have a relationship indeed but since you pass a `C` and `D` to the method and both implement `A` (and `B`) they have something in common, i.e. they both are `A`s.

That means the following would work:

```
A a = addBox2(new C(),new D()); //common type is A
B b = addBox2(new C(),new D()); //common type is B
S s = addBox2(new C(),new D()); //common type is S
Object o = addBox2(new C(),new D()); //common type is Object
```

As long as type inference can solve the generic type from the assignment as well as the parameters it should work (note that type inference isn't as good in Java versions prior to 8, especially in 5 and 6).

You can, however, define the type yourself by passing it to the method call:

```
A a = EnclosingClass.<S>addBox2(new C(),new D()); //static method within EnclosingClass
A a = this.<S>addBox2(new C(),new D()); //instance method
```

In both cases you define the generic type to be `S` and thus the assignment won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Type parameter `U` is inferred from the type of the `a` variable you are assigning the result of `addBox2(...)` to, which in your case is `A`. As both `C` and `D` implement `A` it works flawlessly.

The following of course won't work:

```
S s = addBox2(new C(),new D());
A a = s; // compile error, type mismatch
```

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA for development and IDEA shows me that T is inferred as S. May be IntelliJ is showing me the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Eclipse and IntelliJ aren't annotating these properly. With this (slightly tweaked) example:

```
public static <U> U getU(U u1, U u2) {
  return u2;
}

static interface A {}
static class S {}
static class C extends S implements A {}
static class D extends S implements A {}
static class T implements A {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a = getU(new C(), new D());
  A b = getU(new C(), new T());
}
```

I see the following when I mouse-over the first call to `getU()` in `main()`:

> `<? extends S> ? extends S analysis.Delme.getU(? extends S u1, ? extends S u2)`

Which is clearly not correct - `A` does not extend `S`. I suspect Eclipse is mistakenly oversimplifying the generics here, and preferring to report that `C` and `D` both extend from `S`, rather than both implement `A`.

If I mouse-over the second call I instead get the much more reasonable:

> `<A> A analysis.Delme.getU(A u1, A u2)`

Which is presumably what the compiler is *actually* doing here for both calls.

---

Note as `Thomas` points out, even if two classes have nothing in common (such as `S` and `T`) they still extend from `Object`, so `Object c = getU(new S(), new T());` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t trust the tooltip of an editor that might not cope with complex generic constructs. The inferred type is `S & A & B` (before Java 8), which can be assigned to `A`. In Java 8, the inferred type is just `A`, as generic method invocations are so-called *poly expressions* using the target type. For your `addBox` invocation, it makes no difference.

To illustrate the issue, you may write

```
Object o = Arrays.asList(new C(), new D());
```

in Eclipse using Java 7 compliance mode, and hover the mouse over `asList`. It will print
`<? extends S> List<? extends S> java.util.Arrays.asList(? extends S... a)`, similar to the `addBox` invocation of your question, but when you change the code to

```
List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new C(), new D());
```

you get the compiler error “Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<S&A&B>` to `List<A>`” (still in Java 7 mode), showing that the actual inferred type is `S & A & B`, not `? extends S`.

When you turn the language compliance level to Java 8, the compiler error will go away, as in Java 8, the target type will be used to infer the type, which will be `A` instead of `S & A & B`.

As said, for your `addBox` invocation, it makes no difference whether `A` or `S & A & B` is inferred, as both can be assigned to `A`, so it works under both, Java 7 and Java 8 compliance level. But when you use an invocation, where it makes a difference, like with `Arrays.asList`, you can see the actually inferred type, which is never `? extends S` as the editor’s tooltip claims…